# Filter the gridview on the basis of dropdown list ID. [Outside Gridview]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a dropdown list which is outside the gridview. The dropdown list values are coming from master table. I want on the basis of the selected value of the dropdownlist the data in the gridview should get filtered. Please help me achieve this as I am new to this and haven't did it before.
See my dropdownlist code:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPagesNgo" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker form-control-drp wd" Style="width: 100%" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Cs code:-

```
 private void Binddropdownlist()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_ngoname", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlPagesNgo.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ngo_name"].ToString();
        ddlPagesNgo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ddlPagesNgo.DataBind();
        ddlPagesNgo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select NGO--", "0"));
    }
```

Also see the gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCSRPageData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="grdCSRPageData_DataBound" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="hoverTable"
                OnPageIndexChanging="grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDeleting="grdCSRPageData_RowDeleting" 
                PageSize="5" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="grdCSRPageData_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdCSRPageData_RowUpdating" 
                OnRowCancelingEdit="grdCSRPageData_RowCancelingEdit">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="k-alt" BackColor="#f5f5f5"/>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Checkbox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_title"  HeaderText="Page Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_description" HeaderText="Page Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_title" HeaderText="Meta Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_keywords" HeaderText="Meta Keywords" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_description" HeaderText="Meta Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
                        <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:CommandField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Do let me know if you need anything else.

Get data function code:-

```
  private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get selected value on selected index changed event of dropdown and pass this value to query genearting datasource to be bound to gridview

```
protected void ddlPagesNgo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BindGrid(ddlPagesNgo.SelectedValue);


}
```

Your dropdowlist should now be

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPagesNgo" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker form-control-drp wd" Style="width: 100%" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPagesNgo_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Changes to gridview binding function

```
    public void BindGrid(int selectedID) 
    { 
    string strQuery = "select Id,page_title,page_description,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,Active from tbl_Pages";
    strQuery +=" WHERE Id = "+selectedID; 
    strQuery +=" ORDER By Id DESC"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery); 
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd); 
    grdCSRPageData.DataSource = dt; 
    grdCSRPageData.DataBind(); 
    }
```

Also have a look at [**parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection attack.**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

Comment: what is `getDataTable` here ?

Comment: getDataTable() is a function in which you will write your Select query to retrieve data of your gridview . Yop would pass dropdownlist selected value and use this value in WHERE clause

Comment: I have written `getData` function already. The values in dropdown list are coming from a master table. whose Id is mapped with other table which are in gridview. I need to map on the basis of Id. So please help me in that way. I know that is not tough but i am not able to proceed.

Comment: Ok , also show the text of SqlCommand being passed to GetData() , this where value of dropdownlist has to be added..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66637/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-mmhasannn).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do the following:

1. On Dropdown value change - submit form (AutoPostBack="true").
2. Add SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) event handler to
   your Dropdown.
3. Call Binddropdownlist with some parameter.
4. Modify Binddropdownlist  so that where condition is created for query
   basing on parameter value.   Rebind gridview with new data from
   query.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your Gridview on DropdownSelectedIndex Changed. On DropdownSelection check

```
        protected void ddlgrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         bindGridview();
         if (ddlgrid.SelectedItem.Value == "1") // Dropdownlist Value 
         {
              // Write your Sql Procedure or Query To Display result 

         //  It will return only selected value in Gridview.
         }
        if (ddlgrid.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
         {
             // same here 
         }
     }
```